# Remove all scripts with javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to remove all scripts tags with content from the string of the type below with regex in javascript.
But I am still getting as output:

```
");</script>
```

when it should be an empty string.

The code is:

```
var BG = '<script type="text/javascript">document.write("<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"http:\/\/site;js=y;target=_blank;time="+ (window.emediate_time ? window.emediate_time : window.emediate_time = new Date().getTime()) +"1053997930;"><\/script>");</script><script type="text/javascript" src="some?cre=mu;js=y;target=_blank"></script>';

BG = BG.replace(/<\s*script.*?>.*?(<\s*\/script.*?>|$)/ig,'');
```

Could you please tell me what's wrong and how to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: /<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/gi

Comment: this is the good answer for me !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
(/<.*?script.*?>.*?<\/.*?script.*?>/igm, '')
```

or

```
(/<script.*?>.*?<\/script>/igm, '')
```

(you need 'm' switch to search multi-line)

Comment: you need 'm' switch to search multiline.

Comment: There is no need for multiline mode, and a script tag must start with `<script`.

Comment: You are not understanding multiline mode correctly. It is only used when a regex contains `^` or `$`, and you want them to match the start and end of a line, rather than of the whole string.