# Remove script elements from html string converting query string to symbol

Tags: javascript, html, encoding

I am using this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659351/removing-all-script-tags-from-html-with-js-regular-expression) to remove script elements from ajax responses. However, when my response looks like this :

'console.log("test");https://x.ya.com/home?abc=1&currency=EUR'

It converts the &curren to ¤ symbol.

The result looks like this:
'https://x.ya.com/home?abc=1¤cy=EUR'

How do I avoid this?

Comment: There are a lot of poor answers on that question. Which one are you using specifically? Post code.

Comment: I am using the top answer to the question : Here is the code

 function stripScripts(s) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = s;
    var scripts = div.getElementsByTagName('script');
    var i = scripts.length;
    while (i--) {
      scripts[i].parentNode.removeChild(scripts[i]);
    }
    return div.innerHTML;
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the approach as mentioned in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816815/remove-all-scripts-with-javascript-regex). This removes all the script elements from the text without treating it as html (without creating a div and appending the text to innerHTML of the div), which solves the case.

No html = no html symbol decode.

Works for me!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, sorry I couldn't help much

Answer (score 1):

Try using the escaped ampersand `&amp;` to represent the character `&` in the HTML where this problem occurs, like so;

**HTML**

`<a href="http://example.com/home?abc=1&amp;currency=EUR">Example Link</a>`

**Produces**

[Example Link](http://example.com/home?abc=1&currency=EUR)

Comment: i dont have control over the url.. this was just an example.. there could be multiple others.

Comment: I'm a bit unsure as to what you are doing, can you not replace the string "&currency" with "&amp;currency" at any stage with what you're doing? Even in a small script in JavaScript?

Comment: its not just about &curren, there are a hundred other cases. Replace is just not going to work.