# Remove scripts from html string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove `<script>` tags from an html string using regex.

I have the following code which works, but doesn't work when you put back to back scripts:

```
function removeScriptsFromHtmlStr(html) {
  const regex = /<script(?:(?!\/\/)(?!\/\*)[^'"]|"(?:\\.|[^"\\])*"|'(?:\\.|[^'\\])*'|\/\/.(?:\n)|\/\*(?:(?:.|\s))*?\*\/)*?<\/script>/;
  const result = html.replace(regex, '');
  return result;
}
```

So for example:

running this through the funciton will work fine

`<script>alert(document.cookie);</script>`

but this won't:

`<script>alert(document.cookie);</script><script>alert(document.cookie);</script>`

How can I update the regex to fix this?

Comment: add a `g` flag (stands for global). So `/your regex/g`, otherwise only the first match will be replaced

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing all script tags from html with JS Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659351/removing-all-script-tags-from-html-with-js-regular-expression)

Comment: If this is done for security reasons, then don't do it with RegExp, it's far too easy to trick any RegExp you ever can create. Create a DocumentFragment instead, attach the HTML, and remove the script elements from the parsed fragment.

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regex. [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak dang i cant believe i missed that. seems to be working for me, thanks! if you want to post an answer ill accept it

Comment: FYI there are plenty of ways to get break that reg exp.

Comment: If you really end up to do the task using [RegExp](https://imgur.com/ynO1PcJ) ...

Answer (score 0):

Since JavaScript does not support the Singleline `/s` flag you will need to do a workaround for `.`:

```
/<script.*?>[\s\S]*?<\/script>/gi
```

https://regex101.com/r/7iFLnA/1

Answer (score -1):

Lazy loading should do the trick
`<script>(.+?)<\/script>`

Answer (score -1):

try this regex

```
/<script.*?>.*?<\/script>/igm
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15816902/5812095